# Extend a linear functional on "nice" functions to an integral

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, banach-spaces

I have a [positive linear functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_linear_functional) $h$ defined on a set of Lesbesgue-measurable functions of "moderate growth" on $\mathbb{R}^2$–call this set $MG(\mathbb{R}^2)$. (A function $f$ is positive if $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.)  I want to ensure that there is a unique measure $\mu$ such that
$$ h(f) = \int f\, \mathrm{d} \mu \quad\text{for all} \quad f \in MG(\mathbb{R}^2).$$

Let me describe a line of attack. Let $C_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be the set of continuous, compactly supported functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The [Reisz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) ensures that there exists a unique measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that

$$ h(f) = \int f\, \mathrm{d} \mu \quad\text{for all} \quad f \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^2)\subset MG(\mathbb{R}^2).$$

To what extent can I extend this representation to all of $MG(\mathbb{R}^2)$? Is there some general result that ensures positive linear functionals have a unique integral representation for a larger class than just $C_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$? If you have a specific reference, that would be immensely helpful.

Finally, if it helps to have a concrete example in mind, I can take $MG(\mathbb{R}^2)$ to be the set of all measurable functions that grow no faster than $O(\exp(x^2+y^2))$ as $x^2+y^2\to \infty$.

Comment: Do you have a more precise characterisation of $f \in MG(\mathbb{R}^2)$ in terms of the behaviour of $f(x,y)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$? Because if the space $MG(\mathbb{R}^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ is nice enough, you might be able to work things out more easily in terms of $d\nu = e^{x^2+y^2}d\mu$ (i.e., $f \mapsto h(fe^{x^2+y^2})$), and then translate this to a result about $MG(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $d\mu$?

Comment: Assuming that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is not dense in $MG(\mathbb{R}^2)$, then you would have some non-zero linear functional $h$ on $MG(\mathbb{R}^2)$ which is zero on $C_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Some trick with Krein-Milman should give you a positive linear functional, I think.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Thanks, it appears that Yurii has taken your idea and provided a specific example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not expect that the representation

$$ h(f) = \int_{\mathbb R^2} f\, \mathrm{d} \mu \quad\text{for all} \quad f \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^2)\subset MG(\mathbb{R}^2)$$

can be extended to a "much larger" subspace (you can extend it e.g. to $C_0(\mathbb R^2)$) without any additional conditions on $h$. The reason is that $h$ may be nontrivial, but equal to zero on $C_c(\mathbb R^2).$ You can construct such $h$ using [M. Riesz extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Riesz_extension_theorem).

Let e.g. $$MG(\mathbb R^2)=\{f\mid f \mbox{ measurable and }|f(x,y)e^{-x^2-y^2}|<C\ \mbox{for some}\ C\}$$ with $||f||=\sup_{x,y}|f(x,y)|e^{-x^2-y^2}.$ Define $h$ on the subspace

$$
F=\{f\in C(\mathbb R^2)\mid \exists\lim_{x^2+y^2\to\infty} f(x,y)e^{-x^2-y^2}\}
$$
as $$h(f)=\lim_{x^2+y^2\to\infty} f(x,y)e^{-x^2-y^2}$$ and extend it to a positive functional on $MG(\mathbb R^2).$ Then $h\equiv 0$ on $C_c(\mathbb R^2),$ hence $\mu\equiv 0$ ($\mu$ as in Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem).

Comment: Just a note: this argument trivially works if we replace $C_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$. (In general, this fact is due to density of $C_c$ in $C_0$, but it is also easy to see directly.)